# Is new value coming from the distribution of the previous points?

Tags: change-point, pre-post-comparison

I have a set of 30 data points, measuring percent of acknowledgement of an event that should not happen. So ideal value is 0.0 but we are getting some values greater than that, of order $10^{-5}$. It is not time series data.

A person has elicited an upper bound. If this is crossed, we ring some bells, but we want a more data-driven approach so we thought, let's use the previous data points to create a distribution, extract 'some interval' and if next point is outside that 'interval', ring the bells.

We also thought that if a 'suspicious' value comes, we can say (after investigation) if it is 'guilty' so we can make it 'contribute' or not to the created distribution.

How can we achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

The type of method you are looking for here is annomally/outlier detection. The most basic way that I can think of doing this would be to understand from what statistical distribution your data comes and using this distribution to detect highly unlikely values.

From what you described, we can affirm that your data contains only non-negative values and lower values are more likely than higher ones (and that there is an upper bound of one that probably nevers really happens). This could be fitted into the family of [exponential distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution).

That said, is very important to note that nothing can be affirmed here for sure without seeing the data itself and maybe without more understating of the process that generates this data.

It is possible that something as simple as:

1. fitting an exponential distribution on the average of your past data
2. getting a higher bound on the 95% percentile

works for you. It is also possible that this approach gets to an upper bound that is much higher (or lower) than what makes sense to your problem. It depends on the data and what you want from it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sold on this being about anomaly detection. You believe that if some to-be-determined threshold is crossed, that means there is a problem. It could be that this threshold is crossed far too often for these events to be considered anomalies, perhaps even most of the time. However, no matter how often this threshold is crossed, whenever it is crossed, that suggests a problem.

Therefore, give thought to how your system works. How often can this "event that should not happen" happen before there is a problem? That question should drive your decision-making. If you determine that such a threshold is routinely crossed, that tells you something about the process that generates these events that should not happen, since they are, indeed, happening.